# django chaning filter continuously

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm trying to make continuous django filtering.

Let's assume that I have some model:

```
class TextModel(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And now, I'll make TextModel's objects like it:

```
{'text': '1'}, {'text': '2'} ... {'text': '99'}, {'text': '100'}
```

Here starts what I want to do.

I'll find objects that text field include '1' by 4 Querysets.

As you know final result will be this:

```
{'text': '1'}, {'text':'10'}, {'text':'11'} ... {'text':'91'}, {'text':'100'}
```

Maybe it's length will be 20? maybe 20 result.

I want to make this result divided by 4 Querysets that has 5 results individually. And I want to make results be ordered by their `text length`, not `pk` or `created`. But if `text length` is the same, then it is good to be ordered by 'pk' or 'created'. Most urgent ordering standard is `text length`

I tried:

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Length

TextField.register_lookup(Length)

qs1 = TextModel.objects.filter(Q(text__icontains='1')).order_by(
                    Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]
qs2 = TextModel.objects.filter(Q(text__icontains='1') & Q(text__lte=len(qs1.last().text)).order_by(
                    Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]
qs3 = TextModel.objects.filter(Q(text__icontains='1') & Q(text__lte=len(qs2.last().text)).order_by(
                    Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]
qs4 = TextModel.objects.filter(Q(text__icontains='1') & Q(text__lte=len(qs3.last().text)).order_by(
                    Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]
```

This has failed. Because `qs2` also has the result that is also in `qs1`.

To prevent this, I thought this way:

```
qs1 = TextModel.objects.filter(Q(text__icontains='1')).order_by(
                    Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]

qs2 = TextModel.objects.filter(Q(text__icontains='1') & Q(text__lte=len(qs1.last().text)).order_by(
                    Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]

for item in qs1:
    qs2 = qs2.exclude(pk=item.pk)
qs2 = qs2.order_by(Length('text').asc(), 'pk')[:5]
```

But I think it's not good idea. It seems to be not the best idea.

**Question:** How to solve it in better way? How to filter it?

Comment: Querysets are sets and therefore support [these set operators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) that you can use. For example if you want to exclude all `qs1` elements from `qs2` you can do `qs2 = qs2.difference(qs1)`. Note that you probably don't want to slice your QuerySet (`[:5]`) `qs2` until *after* you removed the elements from `qs1`.

Comment: The problem that I don't understand is why you need 4 different query sets. Normally you would use [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) to split your results in groups of 5: First order by text length, then just paginate. Each page will have the next 5 results.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry, pagination is not good in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that a `QuerySet` is a set and therefore supports [these set operators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union), one of which is `difference()`. So if you have a queryset (`qs1`) that you want to exclude from another queryset (`qs2`), you can do:

```
qs2 = qs2.difference(qs1)
```

Note that your `qs2` query should not be sliced *before* applying the difference, because slicing should always be the last operation. Otherwise you might get SQL errors.